# Set View's internal name/url

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I am using SharePoint PnP Powershell to create a view. In order to do this, I am using `New-PnPView` command and everything works. What I would like to do is set view's internal name.

for e.g. List Title will be 'All Items' but the internal name should be 'AllItems.aspx'

For now, New-PnPView takes Title as internal name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a CSOM limitation wherein the `ViewCreationInformation` object doesnt have a property to set the URL. It takes only the Title value.

Also, the correct commandlet to create view is `Add-PnPView`. Would suggest that you update your PnP PowerShell to the latest version.

So, what you can do is use the `Add-PnPView` commandlet to create a view as:

```
Add-PnPView -List "My List" -Title "AllItems" -Fields "Title","Address"
```

After that, you can use the `Set-PnPView` commandlet to set the view's title as below:

```
Set-PnPView -List "My List" -Identity "AllItems" -Values @{Title="All Items"}"
```

Comment: Excellent, will definitely give it a try